# how to disable app extension for lower ios version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I'm building a FileProvider extension for iOS 11, but we already get Document Picker View Controller extension to provide UI for iOS 10.This causes Document picker will pop out even in iOS 11.

we don't need Document Picker View Controller extension in iOS 11.

My question is how to disable Document Picker View Controller extension just for iOS 11 and later?

Comment: Please add the screenshot of code and screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figure this out on my own.

Apple Document says this

> If you're updating an existing File Provider extension, be sure to set the NSExtensionFileProviderSupportsEnumeration key to YES in your extension's Info.plist file. If you're creating a new extension, Xcode automatically sets this key for you.

but they forget to mention that you should put NSExtensionFileProviderSupportsEnumeration key inside the NSExtension dictionary not just in that plist file.

The right plist should be looking like this

[image]

Comment: Nice observation :)